# I want to feature faded images behind the text on some pages in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

Can anyone tell me please how to simply insert one specific image behind the text etc on **single** page in LibreOffice 5.0.4/2?

I've tried various configurations and looked at many forums, but I keep getting the image either on all pages or on every-other page or some other weird configuration.

Answer (score 0):

## How to insert an image behind text in LibreOffice Writer on a single page

By default, the image should only appear on the page you inserted it.

1. From the menu, choose `Insert` → `Image...`
2. Adjust image as desired (eg by size)
3. From the menu `Format` →  `Wrap` → `In Background`

   (the same effect can be achieved by right clicking on the image and choosing `Wrap` → `In Background`)

Illustrated:

[image: because a picture tells a thousand words, or five paragraphs of lorem ipsum]